# If value in column A equal to value in another column

Tags: excel

Here is my problem, I have a CSV file with 4 columns. Column 1 is for product ID and column 2 is for the price of the corresponding product.
Column 3 and 4 are about the combination of products, such that column 3 refers to the product ID and column 4 is the price of the combination.

I need a function that check every similar values in column 1 and 3, and if the value in every cell of the third column is corresponding to a value of the first column, I want to add the value of the second column (price of the base product)in the 5th column next to the combination price.

for example :

https://i.ibb.co/ZdN5mJ3/Capture.png

(the screen is an simplified example, I have hundred of entries on the original file)

So here the function I need should add in the Column E 66.58333 in the first two cells, 62.083333 in the three next cells and 64.1666667 in the last cell of Column E.

I've search in a lot of forums, but I didn't find anything helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in Column E?

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,1)
```

Comment: sadly It doesn't work , I have a popup error when trying to apply the function :(

Comment: Is it? It worked for me fine, You can also give =VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,0), Did you give it exactly the same.What is the error that you get?

Comment: here is what I've got :
https://i.ibb.co/52k47zr/Capture.png  (sorry the error message is in French)
maybe I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Not sure why it is not working for you.:( You can try with a simple file once.